# Broadcast the change to system after set system environment variable

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, sendmessage

I am working on adding system environment variables to Windows via Python.

I tried via Python library. It was able to add system environment variables; however, program doesn't recognize newly added system environment variables.
I ran as admin Python code and restart PC after added system environment variables.

I thought I didn't broadcast newly added system  environment variables. Therefore, I used "SendMessage" to broadcast newly added variables to system.

However, it didn't really work.

I used "Edit the environment variables" on windows to add system variables manually. It was working and program recognized new system  environment variable. However, code below does add variables on system environment variables part. But program doesn't recognize for some reasons.

I am not sure what I miss. Anybody knows what I missed?

Thanks!

```
def set_system_env(name, value):
    path = r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment'
    hklm = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
    try:   
        key = OpenKey(hklm, path, 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE)
    except:
        self.log("Error")
    SetValueEx(key, name, 0, REG_EXPAND_SZ, value)
    CloseKey(key)
    broadcast_env_change()

def broadcast_env_change():
    SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 'Environment')
def add_sys_val()
    set_system_env("Test_PATH" , "C:\System_Folder")
```

Answer (score 0):

The broadcast message only notifies Windows applications that are listening for the message, such as the Desktop process.  The environment is normally inherited from the parent process and doesn't change unless the *current process* changes it, such as listening for the broadcast message and updating its own environment.

Comment: Is there any ways to  system environment variables via python? I checked similar questions in stack overflow (with other language) What they doing is very similar to code that i write..

Comment: @NBB You don't have a [mcve] for me to verify.  Make sure all the code is present, such as imports.  Did you check that registry location to make sure it was updated before rebooting?  Your question was about broadcasting, which is all I addressed.  Normally you will need to reboot or at least restart your program from the desktop (which does receive broadcast messages) before seeing the change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure how to check make sure that registry location. How I can check it and what do i need to do with registry location?  I search API to added system variable. When my code doesn't work, i searched that i need to broadcast to system that i added new variable on system......

Comment: Use the `regedit` tool and view the `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` location.